Polygons on 2D plane: Calculate the exact shift to resolve overlaps
I'm working with polygons on a 2D plane that have Tetris-style gravity. Each polygon can rest either on the X-axis or on top of another polygon. If a polygon overlaps with any other polygon(s), it needs to be shifted along the Y-axis to resolve the overlap.
Before the shift:

After the shift:

The goal is to find the exact minimal vector needed to shift the polygon upwards (the X-coordinate remains the same) so that it no longer overlaps with others while maintaining the Tetris-gravity effect.
One approach could be to move the polygon incrementally in a loop until there’s no overlap. However, I’m concerned that might be inefficient. Also, I already have formulas for linear interpolation, but I’m not sure how to apply them in this case—or if there’s a better way. Any insights or methods for calculating the vector would be appreciated!

does without looping mean you do not want to loop with 2 polygons until you found where they not overlap anymore or you do not want to loop at all i.e. if you had a formula how to disoverlap 2 polygons you would not want to loop through all combinations of polygons until you found the combination with the least height?

Can you please confirm that you are looking for the minimal shift up? You mentioned the Tetris, so it looks like the moving polygon falls from above onto the set of static polygons until the first collision. The minimal shift solution can produce a polygon, differing from the Tetris-like-falling-from-above polygon (not in the configuration in the picture)

@Ichwerdennauchsonst The first one.

@HEKTO Yes, I'm looking for the smallest possible upward shift; otherwise, the polygon will appear to float. Could you explain how this might differ from what I’m aiming for?

For example, if you have a small triangle ABC, which can fit between edges DF and HI or above the edge GI, then you'll have two solutions - the first one with minimal upward shift and the second one with falling-from-above.

As with a lot of polygon-versus-polygon problems which don't involve rotation (see the GJK algorithm for a canonical example), a useful tool here is the Minkowski sum. Rather than determine a translation which resolves penetrations between one polygon and another, you find the MS of the "other polygons" and the reflected-about-the-origin target polygon, and find a point outside that result. Any point outside the MS is a legal translation which resolves the penetration in the original problem.
Your example:

Now we simply scan upwards from the origin, looking for the first point not inside the MS. That point is the optimum upwards translation to resolve the penetration.
The Minkowski sum of two convex polygons is trivial to calculate, so just treat each "other" polygon as a separate MS and find the first point which is outside all of them. This involves finding the embedding depth of the origin (that is, how many MSes the origin is inside), finding all MS edges which intersect the +Y ray, sorting those intersections, then walking upwards through them, adding 1 to the embedding depth when you enter a MS and subtracting 1 when you leave a MS polygon, until the first time that embedding depth goes to 0. That's the solution. Here, the embedding depth starts at 1, goes to 2 at around y=0.75, goes back to 1 at about y=2.9, then goes to 0 at about y=3.3.

Thank you, this is really interesting and I'll look into it!
